# How to handle a massive amount of data callbacks from tcp socket?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

Right now I have a node.js based application (A) that is connected to another application (B) with a tcp socket in order to receive data.

The node.js application has also some validation and processing logic that is executed right after receiving the data from the socket. Finally it writes a result to a database (async).
So far everything worked fine and performance was good. Application B sent up to 20 messages per second. But since Application B has now a new feature there may be up to 2000 messages per second. As soon as Application B sends a lot of messages, Application A almost freezes (Memory goes also up from 30MByte to 100Mbyte). 
After analyzing log files it is very likely that this may be caused due to the amount of messages and the amount of calls to the data callback of the socket. I only need every 20ms a message of Application B, but filtering the messages right after receiving them does also not work. I did some performance measuring:

- processing the incoming message takes about 12ms, maybe I can optimize this part a little
- The filtering from above took only about 30 microseconds

Right now I am thinking about a scenario like this:

B -> A (socket part, one process) -> C (filters and buffers messages, one process) <- A (processing part, one process)

I read about redis pub/sub but I do not really know if it fits my requirements here. The sequence of the messages is critical. 
How would you solve this problem? Is there maybe a point I am missing?

Comment: How the backend processing is made? Since the data is received in a socket, I think a complex situation happens. For example, if you have blocking functions like for-in loops (maybe iterating over 2000 objects!), then the performance can be lower. Other example is the persistence, it can be async but not atomic, say, iterating over a result and make a insert each time instead processing for make one database insert call. Obviously, it depends of the business logic.